# Python Routes, giving request method

Tags: python, routes

I have something like using python routes, How to map request method like post, get, delete here...

```
mapper.connect("/user", controller=user_controller, action="user")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a condition, specify the HTTP method required and map to the appropriate controller action. For example, your snippet could be rewritten as:

```
mapper.connect("/user", controller=user_controller, action="get_user", conditions=dict(method=["GET"]))
mapper.connect("/user", controller=user_controller, action="add_user", conditions=dict(method=["POST"]))
```

See the docs at http://routes.groovie.org/setting_up.html#conditions

Note that if you only want to specify one HTTP method and have all other requests handled by one route, include a matching route without the condition **after** the more specific route:

```
## Handle GET requests
mapper.connect("/user", controller=user_controller, action="get_user", conditions=dict(method=["GET"]))
## Handle all other, non-GET requests
mapper.connect("/user", controller=user_controller, action="add_user")
```